# Thumbnail images not displayed Magento after clearing cache

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Almost all of my thumbnail images are not displayed after I cleared Magento cache from backend. The problem is only with Thumbnail Images of sets available and similar products and related products images . All category and products pages images seems to be fine.

In order to troubleshoot I did the following:

1. Made Media Folder globally read write and executable (`chmod -R 777 ./media`)
2. Cleared cache again and then loaded the pages.
3. Deleted the cache folder of `/var/www/media/catalog/products/cache..` Magento recreated cache still no images were displayed
4. Increased PHP memory limit to 512MB

Any other guesses, I  need to try to fix this. It's only with small thumbnail images and everything was fine until I deleted cache from backend.

Comment: Reindex data then clear cache may be solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check thumbnail option is assigned to image or not in admin,

If assigned then cross check that your database is having the value for that or not

1st: get thumbnail image attribute id by;

```
mysql> select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'thumbnail';
```

2nd: Now check the image path for thumbnail using below query

```
mysql> select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 'here_your_thum_img_attr_id' AND entity_id = 'here_product_id';
```